# Why do I get "RecursionError" implementing Binary Search algorithm?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

I am implementing a Binary Search algorithm that returns:

- In the case the `key` is in the list:  `True` and the position of the
  `key` I am looking for;
- In the case the `key` is not in the list: it returns `False`

Here is my code of the function: `Bin_Search (A, l, r, key)`

```
def Bin_Search (A, l, r, key):
    
    if l == r:
        if A[l] == key:
            return True, l
        else:
            return False
        
    mid = (l+r)//2
    
    if A[mid] == key:
            return  True, mid
        
    if A[mid] < key:
        return Bin_Search(A, l, mid-1, key)
    else:
        return Bin_Search(A, mid+1, r, key)
```

But I am having trouble since sometimes it works and sometimes not.
For example, implementing the function on the array `A` to find `key = 14`

```
A = [35, 21, 49, 0, 46, 5, 1, 14, 50, 34]
Bin_Search (A, 0, len(A), 14)
```

I get the following error:

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-380483777517> in <module>
     19 
     20 A = [35, 21, 49, 0, 46, 5, 1, 14, 50, 34]
---> 21 Bin_Search(A, 0, len(A), 14)

<ipython-input-174-380483777517> in Bin_Search(A, l, r, key)
     13 
     14     if A[mid] < key:
---> 15         return Bin_Search(A, l, mid-1, key)
     16     else:
     17         return Bin_Search(A, mid+1, r, key)

<ipython-input-174-380483777517> in Bin_Search(A, l, r, key)
     15         return Bin_Search(A, l, mid-1, key)
     16     else:
---> 17         return Bin_Search(A, mid+1, r, key)
     18 
     19 

<ipython-input-174-380483777517> in Bin_Search(A, l, r, key)
     13 
     14     if A[mid] < key:
---> 15         return Bin_Search(A, l, mid-1, key)
     16     else:
     17         return Bin_Search(A, mid+1, r, key)

<ipython-input-174-380483777517> in Bin_Search(A, l, r, key)
     15         return Bin_Search(A, l, mid-1, key)
     16     else:
---> 17         return Bin_Search(A, mid+1, r, key)
     18 
     19 

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-174-380483777517> in Bin_Search(A, l, r, key)
     15         return Bin_Search(A, l, mid-1, key)
     16     else:
---> 17         return Bin_Search(A, mid+1, r, key)
     18 
     19 

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Why do I get this error? Which part of the code I must fix in order that it works properly?

Comment: `return bool` is never used? recursive not terminate.

Comment: You can see that if your code was "def a(x): return a(x)" it would "recurse" until it ran out of stack space, hence the error.   I suspect that because of the arithmetic of index calculation, you end up with a path through the code that has the same effect:   Bin_Search calls Bin_Search calls Bin_Search ...  You might be able to see this by printing out the arguments at the start of every call to Bin_Search.

Comment: What are `Bin_Aearch` and `Binary_Search`?

Comment: Note that binary search only works on sorted data. Your input is not sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def Bin_Search (A, l, r, key):
    
    if l == r:
        if A[l] == key:
            return True,l
        else:
            return False
        
    mid = (l+r)//2
    
    if A[mid] == key:
            return  True, mid
        
    if A[mid] > key:
        return Bin_Search(A, l, mid-1, key)
    else:
        return Bin_Search(A, mid+1, r, key)

#A = [35, 21, 49, 0, 46, 5, 1, 14, 50, 34]
A = [0,1,5,14,21,34,35,46,49,50]
Bin_Search (A, 0, len(A), 14)
```

*****BIG_MISTAKE** : **You should have a sorted list for binary search**

A = [0,1,5,14,21,34,35,46,49,50]

You have mistake in if key is less than mid value you should search for left part instead of right.

```py
if A[mid] > key:
        return Bin_Search(A, l, mid-1, key)
    else:
        return Bin_Search(A, mid+1, r, key)
```